# Eigenvectors on complex space

Tags: linear-algebra

**Suppose $U$ is k-dimensional vector space on complex field, and $S\in L(U)$. Assume $S$ has at least $m$  distinct nonzero eigenvalues. Show that $\def\null{\operatorname{null}} \null (S^{k-m})= \null (S^{k-m+1})$**

Here is my approach:

Suppose $ S \in L(U) $ and k is non-negative integer and $S$ has at least $m$ distinct non-zero eigenvalues. If $S^{k-m} v = 0 $ for all $v \in U$, then $S^{k-m+1} v = S (S^{k-m})=S(0)=0$. Thus, $ \null (S^{k-m}) = \null (S^{k-m+1})$.

Please give me feedback on my answer. If it is wrong, direct me to right track.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why should $S^{k-m}v=0$? Take $k=1$ and $S\neq 0$.

Comment: I just based on the fact that if $S^k = 0$. Any hints? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: the answer there is better than mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032375/null-space-of-transformation