# Null Space of Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, transformation

I am given that $V$ is n-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T \in L(V)$. And $T$ has least $m$ distinct nonzero eigenvalues. How do I show that $\text{null}(T^{n-m}) = \text{null}(T^{n-m+1})$?

I'm really not sure how to start here so just the first couple steps would be very helpful.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $\text{null}(T^{n-m}) \subseteq \text{null}(T^{n-m+1})$.  Suppose there was a vector $\vec{v} \in \text{null}(T^{n-m+1})$ that did not belong to $\text{null}(T^{n-m})$.  Then consider the vectors $\vec{v}_1 := \vec{v}, \vec{v}_2 := T(\vec{v}), \dots, \vec{v}_{n-m+1} := T^{n-m}(\vec{v})$.  Throw in $m$ eigenvectors, one for each of the $m$ distinct nonzero eigenvalues.  Then you have a total of $n+1 = (n-m+1) + m$ vectors, which you can prove are linearly independent (directly, using the definition of linear independence).  This contradicts the fact that $V$ is $n$-dimensional.